# Why is bulk modulus large for a nearly Incompresible material?

Tags: continuum-mechanics, moduli

[image]

[Source of the picture](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Nonlinear+Solid+Mechanics%3A+A+Continuum+Approach+for+Engineering-p-9780471823193)

I don't understand why do we consider a large value of bulk modulus when we want to model incompressibe material? I mean bulk modulus is the bulk change in volume and the material is nearly incompressible, so it seems counter intuitive to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bulk modulus is the amount of pressure divided by the variation in volume, so larger for material hard to compress, formally infinity for "incompressible materials" but of course nothing is **strictly** incompressible.

You might be interested why the word "bulk" is used. This applies to compression in all directions at once.

Another way to compress (or extend) a solid is to push, or pull it along only one direction, leaving the two other directions free. The ratio of the applied one-directional pressure or "pulling force per unit area of section", **divided** by the relative change of size **along that direction**,  is called the "Young modulus". An elastic substance like rubber stretches easily when pulled, and thus has a rather **low Young modulus** (small traction leading to large relative increase), it can still be nearly incompressible, **very high bulk modulus**, because when you stretch it in one direction, it becomes narrower in the two others, keeping the same volume. That would also work for compression, if you take an eraser and squeeze it on its largest face, you will easily reduce its height, but it will spread horizontally, to keep essentially the same volume. Hence "bulk modulus" to distinguish from "Young modulus". And there are even more notions, but this is just to give you a taste.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

A nearly incompressible material has a slight change in volume, thus according to the formula of bulk modulus, the smaller change of volume means a larger value of bulk modulus.